# how to install python 3.9.6 using homebrew on Mac m1

Tags: python-3.x, installation, terminal, homebrew, python-3.9

Im new to programming and stuff and was looking to install python 3.9.6 using home-brew. To do that would I just have to type in `brew install python@3.9` into the terminal, or is there some other way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't ensure a specific version 3.9.6 with brew package `python@3.9`. Homebrew is a package manage designed to get latest pacakge. `python@3.9` will be kept updating to the latest patch version `3.9.x`.

If you REALLY to stick with specific python version, choose `conda` (miniconda is preferred) or `pyenv`.

Comment: right now tho, If I put that command in the terminal, python 3.9.6 will be installed right? If I do that, is there any other steps I would have to do, or would I be good?

Comment: No other steps.

Comment: alright I installed python 3.9.6 with home-brew, but when executing the command "brew list", I find that not only python 3.9.6 is installed, but openss1@1.1 is too. Is that normal?